# Im getting a timeout error while open the cypressin terminal

Tags: cypress

Cypress verification timed out.
Command timed out after 30000 milliseconds
Local\Cypress\Cache\7.4.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=79

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows:

```sh
set CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000
npx cypress verify
```

#### Linux:

```sh
export CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000
npx cypress verify
```

> **CITE:**
>
> [Cypress 9.2.0 introduces a new environment variable 'CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT'](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/02/04/cypress-9.2.0-new-env-variable-cypress_verify_timeout-introduced)
>
> *_ by Mohini Dahiya*